# Webbrowser control doesn't display website correctly

Tags: vb.net

My IE browser is displaying the site http://instasynch.com/rooms/SouthPark completely fine, while the webbrowser control in my VB.net project doesn't. It doesn't load up the chat and the video doesn't start either.

To put it in other words, no scripts work. Without the .ScriptErrorsSuppressed set to true, the website gives many script error warnings.

What could I do?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation

Comment: @HansPassant I don't understand? Could you explain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the Webbrowser control uses IE7 emulation.

This describes how it works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation

What you need to do is add a new DWord value to these keys with the name of your .exe and give it the value of the browser version you want to emulate:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

For example add *YourAppName.exe* with a hex value of *2af9* = emulate IE11

If you're debugging in Visual Studio, you can add *YourAppName.vshost.exe*