# WebBrowser Not Rendering Site Correct

Tags: vb.net

I have a program and the PC it runs ons OS is Win10, The browser is Edge. I understand it uses its Edge browser or IE as default. When i load my site on edge itself it loads fine, if i load it via the web browser panel it loads completely different and bugs out at times!

I noticed an issue were if i load it via the webbrowser component the two arrows that appears, one should be greyed out and not selectable but it appears and if pressed, does nothing.. BUT, if i zoomed out? It fixes itself and now works. Very strange i must say.

I changed my reg keys with the app name and still not fixed.
Above above on this reg key edit found: [Webbrowser control doesn't display website correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663399/webbrowser-control-doesnt-display-website-correctly)

Comment: When debugging the current application will be `<your app name>.vshost.exe`, thus it won't work in the VS debugger unless you add a registry key for that too. -- Implement a code solution instead that modifies the registry for the current process. See below:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vb.net Visual Studio Web Browser Navigate Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365833/vb-net-visual-studio-web-browser-navigate-bad-request)

Comment: Perhaps try using a different web browser control?

Comment: @VisualVincent I dont do it with debugging, i take the exe from the bin location and run it that way.

Comment: Well, try it anyway. I don't know if you did it correctly or not, but as far as I've tested my code works. It can't hurt to try. ;)